# Правильно ли я использую GetTickCount?

Tags: c++, winapi

Дали задание на лабораторную
Сделать программу разграничения доступа,замеряет скорость набора фразы на клавиатуре с использованием функции GetTickCount.
То есть ввожу фразу,он записывает её в текстовый файл вместе количеством миллисекунд полученных с помощью функции GetTickCount
После того как он запомнил её,предлагается снова ввести фразу с нужной скоростью клавиатуры.Если фраза и скорость ввода с клавиатуры совпадают то Вход выполнен,иначе Вход не выполнен.

Моя программа всегда выдаёт вход не выполнен,хотя я засекал.
Может быть я неправильно использую функцию GetTickCount.Прошу совета.

Сам код программы:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void zapisvfail()
{
    char phrase[100]="";
    DWORD startTime=GetTickCount();
    DWORD delta;
    cout<<"Введите фразу"<<endl;
    cin>>phrase;
    delta=GetTickCount()-startTime;
    char result[10];
    _itoa(delta,result,10);
    ofstream outfile("resultingfile.txt");
    outfile<<phrase;
    outfile<<result;
}

void checking()
{
    DWORD startTime=GetTickCount();
    DWORD delta,delta1;
    char checkphrase[100]="";
    char phrase[100]="";
    char result[10];
    ifstream infile("resultingfile.txt");
    infile>>phrase;
    infile>>result;
    delta1=GetTickCount()-startTime;
    char result1[10];
    _itoa(delta1,result1,10);
    cout<<"Введите фразу:"<<endl;
    cin>>checkphrase;
    if((strcmp(phrase,checkphrase)==0) && (result1==result) )
        cout<<"Вход выполнен"<<endl;
    else cout<<"Вход не выполнен"<<endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    zapisvfail();
    checking();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы можете на глаз определить разницу между 7.003 секунд и 7.015 секунд? Вы супермен?

Comment: я засекал 30 секунд и по 1 минуте

я не супермен

Comment: Но сравниваете-то вы миллисекунды. Считаете разницу между 60.003 секунд и 60.015 секунд.

Comment: попробую преобразовать в double и округлить до целого числа

Answer (score 1):

Класс std и все его функции изучу позже.Завтра надо сдавать просто.А тут ещё 2 программы делаю.

Пока возникла такая идея.
Я получаю время затем вычисляю и округляю его до однозначного числа и после сравниваю с временем ввода фразы во 2-ой раз.И вывожу на экран значения для себя чтобы наглядно отслеживать и не заглядывать в текстовый файл каждый раз.

В этом пример даже при совпадении секунд он тоже не впускает.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void zapisvfail()
{
    char phrase[100]="";
    DWORD startTime=GetTickCount();
    DWORD delta;
    cout<<"Введите фразу"<<endl;
    delta=GetTickCount()-startTime;
    delta=(delta*10)/1000;
    floor(delta);
    cin>>phrase;    
    cout<<delta<<endl;
    ofstream outfile("resultingfile.txt");
    outfile<<phrase;
    outfile<<delta;
}

void checking()
{
    DWORD startTime=GetTickCount();
    DWORD delta,delta1;
    char checkphrase[100]="";
    char phrase[100]="";
    ifstream infile("resultingfile.txt");
    infile>>phrase;
    infile>>delta;
    cout<<"Введите фразу:"<<endl;
    delta1=GetTickCount()-startTime;
    delta1=(delta1*10)/1000;
    floor(delta1);
    cin>>checkphrase;
    cout<<endl; 
    cout<<delta1<<endl;
    if((strcmp(phrase,checkphrase)==0) && (delta1==delta) )
        cout<<"Вход выполнен"<<endl;
    else cout<<"Вход не выполнен"<<endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    zapisvfail();
    checking();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы все делаете не правильно и дело не в `GetTickCount`, а в логике.

Во-первых в функции `checking` вы замеряете не время ввода фразы пользователем, а время чтения фразы и времени из файла "resultingfile.txt". Лучше сделайте отдельную функцию для получения фразы от пользователя и измерения времени ее ввода. И используйте эту функцию и в `sapisfail` и в `checking`. И еще рекомендую вам для работы со строками использовать не массивы символов, а класс `std::string`:

```
DWORD get_phrase_and_time(std::string & phrase)
{
   DWORD startTime = GetTickCount();
   std::cin.get_line(phrase);
   return GetTickCount() - startTime;
}
```

Во-вторых, как вам указали в комментариях, правильно было бы проверять не строгое равенство времен ввода, а учитывать погрешность измерения. То есть так примерно:

```
if(std::abs(time1 - time2) < TIME_ACCURACY)
{
   std::count << "Вход выполнен\n";
}
```

В-третьих стоит учитывать что со временем скорость ввода пароля существенно растет, поэтому по-хорошему время ввода нужно записывать каждый раз при входе. Либо учитывать среднее время за несколько наборов.

Comment: Спасибо,я это проверю сейчас проверяю ещё 2 варианта.
Код переделал немного.

Comment: Для считывания строки из консоли `operator>>` мало подходит, лучше использовать `getline`

Comment: @beginner Пожалуйста конечно, но поясню вам как новичку, не надо писать лишние комментарии. Любой текст который вы здесь оставите должен быть полезен не только вам или мне, а каждому кто посетит эту страницу. RuSO не форум, в этом его сила!

Comment: @ixSci Считаете что можете улучшить ответ - исправьте его.

Comment: @Cerbo, при «живом» авторе ответа, исправлять его ответ противоречит элементарным нормам приличия.

Comment: @ixSci Я к этому отношусь нормально